# After changing graphics driver, my computer boot with no display signal, no tty1 ,no grub menu, not even live usb!

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, graphics

I have changed my graphics driver to use the `Using X.Org X server` in the additional driver of software sources. [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSmGc.png) is a demo screenshot of the settings, but it is collected  from internet.

Then when I reboot, there is no signal in the display monitor, it goes to sleep. But the cpu, keyboard, mouse - all are running.

I have tried `CTRL+ALT+F1` to get into the tty1 terminal, failed!
I have tried with a live USB, but still no signal in the display.
I have searched for the solution. But all the solutions out there requires a terminal or grub menu, which I don't get now

So basically , I don't have any access to the display or terminal interface or grub menu.
What can I do now?

My ubuntu is - Ubuntu Budgie 20.04
My GPU is - G210

Comment: Xorg isn't a driver, but a display server (the alternative is Wayland depending on your *unstated* release of Ubuntu).  Please clarify your question.  (Xorg & Wayland are much lower in the stack (user space), and aren't kernel modules which is the technical term for a *driver*)

Comment: @guiverc sorry for that mistake. I have updated the question and also added a demo screenshot of the page where I changed.